# Codeigniter giving blank page after form submit

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, authentication

I'm working on a login system for codeigniter and after the login form is submitted, the page just comes up blank. I have the following code, with echo's inserted to help me find out where things go wrong.

I have development mode set in the index.php mode and E_ALL in php.ini and receive errors on some other pages successfully.

Controller for /account/login:

```
public function login()
{
    echo "made it back into controller";
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = "Log in";

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ( $this->form_validation->run() === FALSE )
    {
        echo "unable to validate";
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('account/login', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data );
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "attempting to login";
        if ( $this->account_model->login() == FALSE ) 
        {
            echo "failed";
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('account/login', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data );
        }
        else
        {
            echo "success";
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('account/successfullogin', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data );
        }
    }

}
```

login() method from Model, called by controller:

```
public function login ()
{

    require 'application/libraries/PasswordHash.php';

    $t_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $hash = $t_hasher->HashPassword($password);
    echo "hashed";

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT `login_token` FROM `Users` WHERE `username` = "'.$this->input->post('username').'" AND `password` = "'. $this->input->post('password').'"');

    echo "query made";
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows();
    echo "query counted";

    if ( $rowCount == 1 ) {
        echo "found row";
        $token = $query->result_array();
        echo "found token";
        $this->input->set_cookie( 'session_token', $token['login_token'], time()+259200, '/', 'notyetcreated.phpfogapp.com');
        echo "cookie created";
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        echo "no beans";
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

With the debug messages I've setup, after submitting the form, I get "made it back into controller attempting to login" and that's it. Any ideas as to what could be causing it?

Comment: replace `===` with `==` in form validation and check

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Doesn't change the end result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this condition in controller

```
 if ( $this->form_validation->run() === FALSE )
```

You can understand more at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: How am I supposed to change this condition? This validates the form based upoon the rules set in the controller and if those pass, returns true else false.
I feel like it's being used correctly. If not, could you point out how?